# How to share objects in vignettes documentation in a R package?

Tags: r, package

I'm writing documentation for my R package using vignettes (which will be embedded in a pkgdown website.
My question is :
if I create an R object in a chunk within a first "aa" vignette.

```
myobject <- mypkg::myfct()
```

How to reuse this object in a second vignette called "bb"?

```
verif <- myobject[myfilters,]
```

I get this error : myobject not found

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a good idea.
You can save this data in an internal RDA file, and load it in the second vignette. See [Chapter 14 External data, R Pakcages](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#data-sysdata).

So you'd have to:

- Create a `data_raw` folder, and have a script that creates this object, then saves it. This is facilitated by `usethis::use_data_raw`, with like "myfct_example".
- Then, at the bottom of this script in `data_raw` ensure that `internal = TRUE`; This will save the object in `R/sysdata.rda`, instead of `data/myfct_example` (if you call that object that).
- Ensure that you run the `data_raw/myfct_example` script every time you change `myfct_example`, so the new version get stored in `R/sysdata.rda`.
- In both vignettes, you'll have this data object available, by `mypkg:::myfct_example`.

Comment: Ok many thanks I thought it was possible

Comment: It is *not* possible, in the sense that you're hijacking a mechanism meant for something else.