Controlling the build order of pkgdown articles
I'm building a pkgdown website for my R package and I need the articles to be built in a specific order due to dependencies between them. The first article saves an output using:
saveRDS(X, 'X.rds')

And the second article retrieves that data using:
readRDS('X.rds')

Currently, the articles are being built in alphabetical order, resulting in an error because the second article is being processed before the data is saved.
In _pkgdown.yml, I've defined the order like this:
articles:
  - title: "First Article"
    contents:
      - "articles/first_article"
  - title: "Second Article"
    contents:
      - "articles/second_article"

But this doesn't seem to control the build sequence; instead, the articles are still being built alphabetically.
Is there another way to specify the build order for articles in pkgdown besides renaming them with numeric prefixes like 01_first_article.Rmd?

I tried a quick example locally in the spirit of what you posted and it didn't work.  Would this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72434750/2727349
